# reading a string into an int array

Tags: java, arrays, int

I want the scanner to read an input with numbers and spaces and put it into an int array, my code is as follows, but even when i enter a valid input such as "5 3 4" I still recieve the "you must specify atleast one rotor". I am a begginner so sorry if the code is messy or not exactly what I need.

```
String rotorConfiguration = scnr.nextLine();

Scanner readRotorConfig = new Scanner(rotorConfiguration);
int [] intRotorConfig = new int[rotorConfiguration.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < rotorConfiguration.length(); i++){
    if (readRotorConfig.hasNextInt()){
        int testRotorConfig = readRotorConfig.nextInt();
        if (testRotorConfig >= 0 && testRotorConfig <= 8){
            intRotorConfig [i] = testRotorConfig;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid rotor. You must enter and integer"
                    + " between 0 and 7");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("You must specify at least one rotor");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? This way you can check the value of the variables to see why the conditionals are/aren't evaluating the way you want.

Comment: Can you please run this code in debug mode to see what the value of `rotorConfiguration` is.  You should also put a breakpoint in the loop to see what the value of `testRotorConfig` is during each evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your for loop is wrong. You are iterating over the length of the string (including spaces) called rotorConfiguration. I think you meant to iterate over the tokens in the string.

```
while(readRotorConfig.hasNextInt(){
  int rotorConfig = readRotorConfig.nextInt();

  //more operations here
}
```

Comment: You should also include logic to handle a case where the next token is not an `int`.

Comment: You also always want to pair your `hasNext..()` calls with the equivalent `next...()` call - using `hasNext()` and calling `nextInt()` will lead to behaviour you generally don't want.

Comment: The OP needs an `i` too

Comment: I was making the assumption that the OP was; controlling his input, and understands the ramifications of using nextInt on unknown inputs. The answer was meant to illuminate the solution, and not to be robust body of code.

Answer (score 0):

One thing

```
int [] intRotorConfig = new int[rotorConfiguration.length()];
```

You have to specify 3 inside `[ ]` but by that line you specify 5 . (as you are mentioning length, you shall measure numbers).

For correcting it, find the frequency of space and then set like this:

```
int [] intRotorConfig = new int[freq + 1];
```

You are doing + 1 because no. of space will be less